# Master equation for system of N discrete states

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

I am given a system with $N$ discrete states $1,2,...,N$. Between this states transitions with rates $\omega_{n\rightarrow m}$ take place, which are non-zero for $m = n \pm1$.
From state $1$ only the transition to state $2$ is possible, from state $N$ only the transition to state $N − 1$.

Now I am supposed to give the corresponding master equation and determine the stationary solution of it.

The master equation I have written down is

$$\frac{dp_n}{dt} = \sum_{n\neq m} \omega_{m\rightarrow n}p_m-\sum_{n\neq m} \omega_{n\rightarrow m}p_m.$$

Next I have written down the first two derivatives for $p_1$ and $p_2$ and set them to zero, which should be the standard approach for a solution.

$$\frac{dp_1}{dt} = \omega_{2\rightarrow 1}p_2-\omega_{1\rightarrow 2}p_1 = 0$$
$$\frac{dp_2}{dt} = \omega_{1\rightarrow 2}p_1+\omega_{3\rightarrow 2}p_3-(\omega_{2\rightarrow 1}+\omega_{2\rightarrow 3})p_2 = 0$$

This lead to following equation:

$$ \omega_{3\rightarrow 2}p_3 = \omega_{2\rightarrow 3}p_2$$

Now I don't know how to proceed, I would appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: The relation between $p_2$ and $p_3$ is similar to the relation between $p_1$ and $p_2$. Therefore, you can show that it is also true for $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$. At the end you can find all of the probabilities in terms of only one of them. Since the sum of probabilities should be equal to one, you can find all of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this really helped. I have one more question. In case that the rates are symmetric $\omega_{n \rightarrow n-1} = \omega_{n-1 \rightarrow n}$ and for the case $\omega_{n \rightarrow n-1} = \omega_{n \rightarrow n+1}$, how can I determine the new normalization factors of the stationary solutions?